# Adding hashrouter to routes makes 'push' to stop render components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-router

I have a ConnectedRouter to which I wanted to add hashes to all the routes so I added the HashRouter component like this:

```
// @flow
import React from 'react';

import { Router, Route,Switch } from 'react-router'
import { HashRouter } from 'react-router-dom'
import { ConnectedRouter } from 'react-router-redux';
import { routerActions } from 'react-router-redux';
import { UserAuthWrapper } from 'redux-auth-wrapper';
import StudiesViewContainer from './components/views/studies/StudiesViewContainer';
import NotificationsViewContainer from './components/views/notifications/NotificationsViewContainer';
import UserView from './components/views/user/UserView';
import StudyViewContainer from './components/views/studies/StudyViewContainer';
import { getUser } from './reducers';
import LoginView from './components/views/login';
import NotFoundView from './components/views/notFound';
import ForbiddenView from './components/views/forbidden';

const UserIsAuthenticated = UserAuthWrapper({
  authSelector: getUser,
  redirectAction: routerActions.replace,
  failureRedirectPath: '/',
  wrapperDisplayName: 'UserIsAuthenticated'
});

const configRouter = (history: Object) => {
  return () =>
    <ConnectedRouter history={ history }>
      <HashRouter>
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/studies" component={ StudiesViewContainer } />
          <Route path="/study/:id" component={ StudyViewContainer } />
          <Route path="/user"  component={ UserView } />
          <Route path="/notifications" component={ NotificationsViewContainer } />
          <Route path="/forbidden" component={ ForbiddenView } />
          <Route path="/not-found" component={ NotFoundView } />
          <Route path="/" component={ LoginView } />
          <Route path="*" component={ NotFoundView } />
        </Switch>
      </HashRouter>
    </ConnectedRouter>
};

export default configRouter;
```

The problem is that when I do something like this:

```
push('studies')
```

The route does not add the hash and the new components are not rendered.

I added the browser history to my store, here is the configureStore file:

```
// @flow
import { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose } from 'redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import createHistory from 'history/createBrowserHistory'
import { routerMiddleware } from 'react-router-redux';
import createSagaMiddleware from 'redux-saga'
import {
  persistStore,
  autoRehydrate,
  createTransform
} from 'redux-persist';

import mainSaga from '../sagas';
import reducer from '../reducers';

const history = createHistory();
const routingMiddleware = routerMiddleware(history);
const sagaMiddleware = createSagaMiddleware();

// Remove error field from persisted auth substate
let authTransform = createTransform(
  (inboundState, key) =>
    key === 'auth' ?
      { ...inboundState, error: undefined }:
      inboundState,
  outboundState => outboundState,
  {
    whitelist: [
      'auth',
      'permissions'
    ]
  }
);

const configureStore = (): Promise<*> => {
  let middlewares = [routingMiddleware,thunk, sagaMiddleware ];
  let composeEnhancers = compose;

  if(process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production') {
    composeEnhancers = window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ || compose;
  }

  const store = createStore(
    reducer,
    composeEnhancers(
      applyMiddleware(...middlewares),
      autoRehydrate()));

  sagaMiddleware.run(mainSaga);

  return new Promise(resolve => {
    persistStore(
      store, {
        whitelist: ['auth', 'permissions'],
        debounce: 500,
        transforms: [
          authTransform
        ]
      },
      () => resolve({ store, history })
    );
  });
};

export default configureStore;
```

Can anyone help me get the `push` working as expected?

I am using the following versions of router in package json:

```
"react-router": "^4.2.0",
"react-router-dom": "^4.2.2",
"react-router-redux": "next",
```

Comment: how did you solve this? I have the same issue

Answer (score 11):

I had a similar problem, I solved it by using

import createHistory from 'history/**createHashHistory**'

instead of

import createHistory from 'history/**createBrowserHistory**'

Also added withRouter when exporting components as suggested in
https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/docs/guides/blocked-updates.md

Answer (score 1):

> I added the browser history to my store, here is the configureStore file:

Most likely that issue lies on difference between `history`-object, used in router, and proposed in redux state. Then history created in redux side `const history = createHistory();`, it seems that it had not linked with `ConnectedRouter` object, but it can't be followed by supposed code.

If valid `history` object is passed to `ConnectedRouter`, try to check that subsequent router actions are to intercepted with `saga` process or other middleware. Try to follow on emitting actions flow by https://github.com/gaearon/redux-devtools tool.

Also you can try to perform manual updating, by adding root component with full lifecycle (Inherited from `React.Component` class), and add there following code:

```
this.props.history.listen((location, action) => {
  console.log("on route change");
});
```

Then you can discover had router state been changed, and if action is taken, just perform `forceUpdate` method in root component. Also consult this documentation: https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/docs/guides/blocked-updates.md

Comment: I'm not using Redux, but doing ```history.listen(() => this.forceUpdate())``` has fixed the issue.